# Disadvantages of using external video adapters

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Are there any disadvantages of using external USB Video adapters ([like this one](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4523263&SRCCODE=CANWGOOCAPLA&cm_mmc_o=mH4CjC7BBTkwCjCECjCE&gclid=CMnf_5WC6rgCFZFcQgodE1IAgQ) ) as opposed to getting another Graphics Card in SLI/Crossfire or just a new graphics card supporting more monitors?

The [current graphics card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150583) that I have in my computer seems to only support running 2 monitors at a time, despite having enough ports to run a lot more.

Can external adapters as I mentioned earlier can cause system instabilities?
What can they handle in terms of graphics?

I Do a lot of video production work and graphic design work, so the monitor/monitors used on the adapter I would have implemented  would likely be used as a preview monitor in premier, or something like that. Do you think I'll run into problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External graphics cards work just like internal graphics cards, except they are far less powerful.

The graphics cards like the one you showed, offload a lot of their rendering to the cpu. The performance will be extremely slow. (Playing solitaire might be pushing it).

That said, they work great for just connecting a second monitor to show spread sheets and the like.

You might be able to get away with playing a movie on the second display.

If you have a spare PCI express slot, definitely buy a new video card. If you don't, your best bet will be to buy it, and return the external video card if it doesn't meet your standards.